# Testing register form fails with password confirmation with Laravel 5

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

I'm trying to test my register form.

I wrote this test :

```
public function testUserRegistration()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'auth/register', array(
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'name' => 'toni',
        'username' => 'toni@free.fr',
        'password' => 'toni19'
    ));

    // Error The given data failed to pass validation.

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

When I run this test, it fails with following error :

**Error The given data failed to pass validation.**

And my controller code :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:users',
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username|email|min:3',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:5'
], User::getFormMessages());
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed  [SOLVED] from the title. Accepting an answer is enough to mark the question as solved; no further action is needed on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss one input like:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'auth/register', array(
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'name' => 'toni',
        'username' => 'toni@free.fr',
        'password' => 'toni19'
        'password_confirmation' => 'toni19'
    ));
```

And validator:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:users',
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username|email|min:3',
    'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:5|same:password'
], User::getFormMessages());
```

From Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-confirmed):

> **confirmed**
>
> The field under validation **must** have a matching field of
>   foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is
>   password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in
>   the input.

Comment: I changed passed data in test function, it works now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome :) glad I could help :)